# Getting attribute of field in serializer (django rest framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from engine.models import Game
from rest_framework import serializers

class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = (
            'game_name',
            'level',
            'game_type',
            'creator',
            'id',
        )
```

I want to get `creator.username` as `creator` just returns the integer of the id of the user object that is the creator. How can I get creator.username instead of creator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override serializer method field as below to get `creator.username` as `creator` as follow:

```
class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    creator = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    def get_creator(self, obj):
        # obj is model instance
        return obj.creator.username

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = (
            'game_name',
            'level',
            'game_type',
            'creator',
            'id',
        )
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this. Hope the `creator` field is read only and is assigned from the view like `request.user`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from engine.models import Game
from rest_framework import serializers

class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    creator = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='creator.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = (
            'game_name',
            'level',
            'game_type',
            'creator',
            'id',
        )
```

**Note :**  This will make the `creator` field read only. If you are planning to add it from the serializer, then use separate name for the `creator.user` name. Just like the following example

```
class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    creator_name = serializers.CharField(read_only=True, source='creator.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = (
            'game_name',
            'level',
            'game_type',
            'creator',
            'creator_name',
            'id',
        )
```

Comment: I ended up finding the answer before you commented and didn't get to try your answer. The answer I found is in line with the answer I 10+'d.